# Asp.net Core Razor RenderPage doesn't work in _layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm reading this tutorial(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/ui-layouts-and-themes/3-creating-a-consistent-look) and trying to add header and footer into layout file.
But Visual Studio is giving an error when I build the project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Structured Content </title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    @RenderPage("~/Shared/_Header.cshtml")
    <div id="main">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        &copy; 2012 Contoso Pharmaceuticals. All rights reserved.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Error message:

Error (active)  CS0103  The name 'RenderPage' does not exist in the current context     c:\apps\Pages\Shared_Layout1.cshtml    8

Comment: Are you really using classic asp.net or asp.net core?

Comment: I created the project with Visual Studio 2022 and selected Asp.net core web app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using .Net Core, while following an old tutorial you'll eventually end up scratching your head. Please note, that the tutorial you are using is referring to Asp.Net Web Pages, which was a nice technology released more then 10 years ago. I know it can get confusing, but nowadays verify, that these tutorials refer to at least .net core 3.1 and upwards. .Net 7 (now again without core) is about to be shipped.

You can use the Partial Tag Helper to render your partial:

```
<partial name="~/Shared/_Header.cshtml" />
```

When using an Html-Helper, it is considered best practices to use the async `Html.PartialAsync` method, though (The tag helper above is already ansynchronous):

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Shared/_Header.cshtml")
```

Feel free to have a deeper look into the docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-6.0

If you are looking for a more up-to-date tutorial please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: great, many thanks, I thought the tutorial is new as the date on it is 07/11/2022

Comment: Yes, many new folks fall in to that trap. Keep an eye on the .net Version referenced. If it says 4.x, it's rather old. .Net core or .Net 5/ 6 / 7 are usually a safe bet. Unfortuantely Microsoft has a reputation with naming schemes :/

Comment: The partial tag helper is asynchronous. No need for the HTML helper at all in Razor Pages

Comment: Thanks @MikeBrind, I've rephrased the answer. Let's pretend that little slip never happened ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is using `RenderPartial`.

```
@{
    await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_Header");
}
```